# Mirroring (flipping) a voltage signal?

Tags: voltage, signal

Which circuit can convert the input voltage signal to either output signal A or B as shown in the image below? 
[image: Mirroring a voltage signal]

Background info: {Update1:This is the signal from a Passive Infrared (PIR) Sensor which needs to wake a SoC.} The SoC has (only) one internal voltage comparator which needs to wake up the processor when a signal crosses a particular threshold in both +ve and -ve direction with respect to a reference voltage. In this example, the processor needs to be woken up when the voltage is either above 2V or below 1.2V, i.e. 0.4V in either above or below 1.6V. So this (hopefully low power) circuit is for that.

Thanks!

Comment: How fast does your input signal change, how quickly do you need to respond, and do you need to respond at all to brief excursions?  If those requirements are not demanding, you could also consider waking up periodically to take an ADC reading.

Comment: Added info about the source of the signal. Chris, The signal is quite low frequency. Using ADC is an option, although it will increase the battery consumption because the SoC needs to be woken up at least every 50 ms. I was looking for a low power/cost external circuit with the internal comparator to do the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget what you think you need and use a window comparator.

[image: Image courtesy datasheetdir]

I know it isn't the lowest-component-count solution or the cheapest but you will be able to configure the scenarios in which your device is woken.

I am confused by your requirements though... usually you reset systems in undervoltage conditions.

Comment: He didn't say that the signal is the supply voltage.

Comment: Thanks HL-SDK for your answer. I've added info about the source of the signal, a PIR sensor. I have used a circuit like this before and it works well for detecting motion.
Now in the current circuit that is being designed, an analog signal to the SoC is preferred since by changing the software even ADC can be used if any complex signal processing is required.
So, the question remains. Any way to mirror a voltage signal?

Comment: @JeannePindar Where do you see the signal being the supply voltage?

Comment: @EarthLord - you can still use the ADC in parallel with this circuit, rather than downstream of a signal-modifying one.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, yes I think that would work although it would use two pins and there are pins available. But still curious to know the answer to this question of mirroring a signal.

Comment: @Kaz I don't. HL-SDK appeared to think it was, based on his reference to resetting systems in undervoltage conditions.

Comment: That's right, I was confused. My answer still stands as a solution to the problem regardless. Your drawings call for a more complicated level shifting and rectifying solution that you do not need.